# Select values lower than another one - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

I have a table with various information and I need to select the values that: 
1) have cod_anag_prov = 0 or = 2 
2) have a count(1)>1

and then set a flag to 1 for each and every single record that respects point 1 and 2 and has the minumum count(1) among all of the occurrences. 
I thought of using the dense_rank function and made up this:

```
SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
   MAX_CNT,
    MIN(MAX_CNT) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY MAX_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY PDRA) OCCORRENZA_MINORE
    FROM 
    (SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
    COUNT(1) AS MAX_CNT
  FROM STM_VOLUME_AGGR
 WHERE (COD_ANAGR_PROV = 0
  OR COD_ANAGR_PROV    = 2)
   GROUP BY PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF
 HAVING COUNT(1)>1
  ORDER BY PDRA);
```

So far (I THINK) I've been able to do what I said before. 
Now, if I have results like these:

```
    34624200    1905    201305  6   6
    34624200    83      201305  13  6
    34624200    93      201305  14  6
    34439201    1       201305  11  2
    34439201    6       201305  2   2
```

and I want to set the flag to 1 for the rows:

```
 34624200   1905    201305  6   6
 34439201   6       201305  2   2
```

how could I do that?! 

 I know I've done something that's far more complex but right now my brain is melting xD (I'm fairly new to SQL)... 

UPDATE 1:
Ok I've done it but surely I need to optimize it. The cost is 3.300.000 :S 
This is my solution:

```
SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
   MIN(MAX_CNT),
    NUMERO_OCCORRENZE FROM
 (SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
   MAX_CNT,
    MIN(MAX_CNT) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY MAX_CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY PDRA) NUMERO_OCCORRENZE
    FROM
    (SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
    COUNT(1) AS MAX_CNT
  FROM STM_VOLUME_AGGR
 WHERE (COD_ANAGR_PROV = 0
  OR COD_ANAGR_PROV    = 2)
   GROUP BY PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF
 HAVING COUNT(1)>1
  ORDER BY PDRA))
  GROUP BY 
  PDRA, COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS, ANNOMESE_RIF, NUMERO_OCCORRENZE
  HAVING MIN(MAX_CNT)=NUMERO_OCCORRENZE
  ;
```

Obviously I'm not sure that this is the best solution (even if it works)...

Comment: What do you mean by "flag"?  Do you mind posting sample input data, so we can help you better? Regardless - it seems all you need right now is to use a GROUP BY clause (and select max(col2), group by the other columns).

Comment: Also, why the plsql tag and reference in your question? This seems like straight SQL all around.

Comment: yeah I've made a mistake with the tag xD

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to be simplified but,
quick win is;

```
    SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
   MAX_CNT,
   row_number() over(partititon by PDRA order by MAX_CNT) rank_id
    FROM 
    (SELECT PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF,
    COUNT(1) AS MAX_CNT
  FROM STM_VOLUME_AGGR
 WHERE (COD_ANAGR_PROV = 0
  OR COD_ANAGR_PROV    = 2)
   GROUP BY PDRA,
    COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS,
    ANNOMESE_RIF
 HAVING COUNT(1)>1
  ORDER BY PDRA)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this happens, when OCCORRENZA_MINORE = MAX_CNT :

```
UPDATE STM_VOLUME_AGGR
   SET flag = 1
 WHERE (PDRA, COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS, ANNOMESE_RIF) IN 
       (SELECT PDRA, COD_DISTRIBUTORE_STARGAS, ANNOMESE_RIF
          FROM ( your_query )
         WHERE OCCORRENZA_MINORE = MAX_CNT)
   AND (COD_ANAGR_PROV = 0 OR COD_ANAGR_PROV = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a group by as mentioned before or another column, which you populate via "case" and a comparison between the last two columns of your query (case ... when equal then 1 else 0 end).